# finding valid pairs of brackets don't work?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am doing a coding question without looking at the answer and I am struggling to find what's wrong with my thought process

> question is to find all combinations of the valid n pairs of brackets

```
public class Foo{
    public void printCombinations(String prefix, int open, int close, int n){
        if (open > n) {
            return;
        }
        if (close > n) {
            return;
        }
        if (open == n && close == n){
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }
        printCombinations(prefix + "(", open + 1, close, n);
        printCombinations(prefix + ")", open, close + 1, n);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        HelloWorld w = new HelloWorld();
        w.printCombinations("", 0, 0, 3);
    }
}
```

When I ran this program, it seemed to print out all combinations instead of ones with valid brackets. I was thinking `printCombinations(prefix + "(", open + 1, close, n);`would ensure that I print opening bracket first then recursively call `printCombinations(prefix + ")", open, close + 1, n);` I see one output with something like `)))(((`. How is this possible if `(` is added first?

Comment: sorry, I realized it didn't look good so i fixed it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because after the recursive calls for `printCombinations(prefix + "(", open + 1, close, n)` are finished on the stack, your code begin to recur `printCombinations(prefix + ")", open, close + 1, n)`. It's why you would get one of string output that begins with `)`, not because of the order you place these two recursive calls. To fix, you need have a condition under which `close` is always less than `open`. As follows,

```
public class Foo{
    public void printCombinations(String prefix, int open, int close, int n){
        if (open > n) {
            return;
        }
        if (close > n) {
            return;
        }
        if (open == n && close == n){
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }
        printCombinations(prefix + "(", open + 1, close, n);
        if (close < open) {   
            printCombinations(prefix + ")", open, close + 1, n);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        Foo w = new Foo();
        w.printCombinations("", 0, 0, 3);
    }
}
```